# Extending a class in a different module, builds in Android Studio but cannot resolve symbols

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

In my project, I have module A with com.example.foo which I want to extend a class in that module in my module B which is com.example.foo.bar. I've added module A as a dependency in module B and it builds just fine.

My problem starts when I'm trying to extend the class as so:

```
package com.example.foo.bar;

public class Subject extends com.example.foo.SomeClass {
    ...
}
```

In Android Studio, all the references to module A show up as red (since it cannot resolve those symbols), **but I can still successfully build my project regardless**.

How do I configure AS to properly recognize the dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution to my problem. This is primarily a bug in Android Studio that's being tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65915

The fix is simple, my project modules all had their own `settings.gradle` in them because they each came from their own git submodule project and AS has a problem ignoring them.

**The "fix" is to delete the settings.gradle from all modules except the root project directory.**

For example, in my situation, my project structure looks like this:

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
library_module:
   build.gradle
   settings.gradle
      library:
         build.gradle
         settings.gradle
android_app:
   settings.gradle
   build.gradle
```

After deleting, the structure looked like this:

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
library_module:
   build.gradle
      library:
         build.gradle
android_app:
   build.gradle
```